# Javascript RegExp for special characters ONLY

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I'm building a real-time password validator. I need to check that at least one of these special characters is present: !@#$%^&*()+

I've seen other questions that also involve alpha characters and numbers, but I need to check **just for the special characters**. This is what I have so far, which kind of works, but stops working when I go back and edit a character in the middle of the text.

**Shortened Code:**

```
$('#account-password').on('input', function () {
    var pass = $(this).val(),
    special = /^[\!@\#\$\%\^&\*\(\)\+]+$/

   // Special Character Check
    if ($(this).val().match(special)) {
        // OK
    } else {
        //Not OK
    }

});
```

**Full Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/jodbu3ta/

What is the correct way to write the regexp for special characters only?

Comment: `^[\!@\#\$\%\^&\*\(\)\+]+$` only matches if **every** character of the input is one of these characters. Don't anchor the expression and repetition is not required. (and I hope you don't restrict the length of the password to 9 characters :-/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for at least one of those special character this regex will be suffice:

```
special = /[!@#$%^&*()+]/
```

Your regex: `/^[\!@\#\$\%\^&\*\(\)\+]+$/` will only match when **all of the input characters** are made of these special characters.

**PS:** Inside character class you don't need to escape these special characters.